# MPAndroidChart: What is used for rendering, just the android.graphics package?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I have checked out the source code a bit and it seems that for rendering only the android.graphics package is used and not directly OpenGL or something, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Across all versions including the current (3.1.0), [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) solely works with the `android.graphics.Canvas` and `android.graphics.Bitmap` for drawing, **no OpenGL**.

Comment: Can you take a look on my question Philipp? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68190761/6444297